# VS2017: Why is debugger breaking on handled exception when DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute is used?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging, exception

When I use DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute and throw exception from delegate or local function, then debugger is breaking on this exception. If I press continue, then program continues to work right and exception gets handled. It is very annoying.

Is this a bug or a feature? How to fix it?

```
[DebuggerNonUserCode]
class Program {


    static void Main(string[] args) {
        try {
            Action act = () => throw new Exception( "Hello World !" );
            act();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Console.WriteLine( "Error" );
        }

        Console.Read();
    }


}
```

**UPDATE**

Why doesn Visual Studio write: `Exception User-Unhandled` ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It should not break unless you've changed the option to break when the exception is thrown. Verify that it is unchecked.

You can do that either by unchecking the option (`Break when this exception type is thrown`) from the `Exception Thrown` dialog

[image]

or by going to `Exception Settings` (<kbd>CTRL+ALT+e</kbd>) and unchecking the option there:

[image]

Comment: I have a little updated question. My exception settings are default. I can uncheck ```Break when this exception type is thrown```. But I'm afraid VS will ignore another exceptions. And it's not good solutiuon. I want to know why doesn ```DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute``` change debugger behavior.